# get custom post meta inside input's value wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress

I have this code:

```
function add_comment_fields($fields) {
$fields['options'] = '<p class="comment-form-options"><label for="option">' . __( 'Choose' ) . '</label>' .
    '<input id="first" name="category" type="radio" value="' . get_post_meta($post->ID, 'agree', true); .'" />'. 
    '<input id="second" name="category" type="radio" value="" />FLASH</p>';

     return $fields;
     }
```

But is not working, I get this output: `Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '.'`

What is going wrong ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You had  a **`;`** here . Try this modified code.

```
get_post_meta($post->ID, 'agree', true); .'"
      ---------------------------------^
```

**Modified Code**

```
<?php
function add_comment_fields($fields) {
    $fields['options'] = '<p class="comment-form-options"><label for="option">' . __( 'Choose' ) . '</label>' .
        '<input id="first" name="category" type="radio" value="'.get_post_meta($post->ID, 'agree', true).'" />'.
        '<input id="second" name="category" type="radio" value="" />FLASH</p>';

    return $fields;
}
```

Comment: Thanks, but now I have another problem the output is empty, it's like this `<input id="first" name="category" type="radio" value="">`. Any idea why? I've tried getting the post meta outside the value attribute and there is working.

Answer (score 1):

You got an extra ; behind the call to get_post_meta(...). Remove that.

```
function add_comment_fields($fields) {
$fields['options'] = '<p class="comment-form-options"><label for="option">' 
                   . __( 'Choose' ) . '</label>' 
                   .'<input id="first" name="category" type="radio" value="'
                   . get_post_meta($post->ID, 'agree', true)
                   .'" />'
                   . '<input id="second" name="category" type="radio" value="" />FLASH</p>';

     return $fields;
     }
```